# Measurability of functions and Daniell integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have just completed a few sessions of self-study of Daniell integral and it naturally extends Riemann integral and I can also see how to use it to "create" measures. However, I am starting to get less a clear picture when it comes to define what we mean for a measurable function. Everything I read either ignore this topic or includes a condition, i.e. Stone's conditions I believe (if $f $ is Daniell integrable, then $\{f\wedge 1\} $ is also Daniell integrable.
I can accept this condition as an axiom, but then what classes of functions do work in creating the lattice vector space one needs in order to introduce Daniell integral?
For instance, if I worked with the the set of continuous functions with compact support (one of the two popular choices, the other being simple functions), is Stone condition fulfilled?
I suppose that measurability is required to show that Daniell integration defines a measure $\mu $ so that Daniell integral is equivalent to a Lebesgue integral with respect to this measure.

I hope that someone with more experience than me could clarify this technical issue. Thank you in advance for any help.

Maurice

Comment: It might help you https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0310v2